# Algorithm for finding the fewest fixed size rectangles required to completely cover set of rectangles

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, geometry, 2d

I have a collection of rectangles of varying sizes at different locations - we'll call this "Collection A".

The goal is to generate a secondary collection of fixed size rectangles (Collection B) that enclose all of the rectangles in Collection A. The rectangles in Collection B will have a fixed size of 2000x1000 pixels. I'm trying to optimize this so Collection B contains the smallest number of rectangles as possible.

[image: Example]

In the drawing above the red rectangles represent Collection A. We're able to contain all of these within 3 fixed size rectangles.

A few rules:

1. All rectangles from Collection A must be contained fully within the bounds
   of a rectangle from Collection B.
2. Collection B rectangles must always be 2000x1000 pixels.
3. Collection A rectangles will be sized somewhere between 50x50px and 1999x999px. Never wider than 1999px or taller than 999px.
4. Collection A rectangles will be distributed throughout an area several times the size of a Collection B rectangle.
5. A rectangle from Collection A is allowed to appear partially or fully within the bounds of multiple rectangles from Collection B, as long as rule 1 is met.
6. All rectangles from both collections will be axis parallel.

I'm sure there are examples of how to solve such a problem out there, but I'm not sure what this problem is called so my searches haven't turned up anything useful.

Comment: According to what I see, the minimum number of rectangles in B can always be 1, because you can create one rectangle that contains all elements in A. However, I think you need to rephrase the description a little to describe the real problem. Or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Are two rectangles from Collection B allowed to overlap?

Comment: @Beemen I thought that too, but one of the requirements is that all the rectangles in B are some fixed size.  Though that was not expressed as one of the rules.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com Is more appropriate for this type of question.

Comment: Can the edges of a rectangle in A touch the edges of the bounding rectangle in B?

Comment: Simply find the farthest left right top and bottom coordinates and then you have the smallest possible rectangle covering all other rectangles.

Comment: @deathismyfriend I believe that one of the inputs is a fixed size for the rectangles in B.

Comment: Just for clarification is one of the inputs a fixed size for the rectangles in B?  If not as others have stated you can just create one bounding box around everything in A.

Comment: @Beeman Correct, if the fixed size of the Collection B rectangles are larger than the whole working domain. This is unlikely to be the case. The size of the rectangles in Collection A are likely to be somewhere between 5-90% the fixed size of the rectangles in Collection B. All of Collection A will be distributed throughout an area many times larger than the fixed size of a Collection B rectangle. I will try to update my question to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's OK for B-rectangles to overlap, then I would do the following. First, for each set of A-rectangles that can be covered by one B-rectangle, enumerate one such B-rectangle. We can slide the B-rectangle up and to the right until it rests against the edges of two A-rectangles, so all we have to do is collect the set of left x-coordinates and bottom y-coordinates from the A-rectangles and, for each element in the direct product, put the lower-left corner of a B-rectangle there.

Now, for each of these B-rectangles, determine the set of A-rectangles that it covers. Then convert the coverage problem to a [set cover integer program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and use an integer program solver to find the optimal solution.